# Large JSON file cannot create classes and use Jsonutility to parse

Tags: c#, json, class, unity-game-engine, parsing

I have a relatively large JSON file generated by a strapi server. I need to read it and display the content in Unity. I have been trying to get this working but have been mostly unsuccesful getting it to work. I have been trying to convert the JSON to classes with converters but I haven't had a succesful result. Can you please suggest the easiest way to do this in unity. I need to access most of these values and have no idea how to do it.

I have been trying to do it with Jsonutils in unity. Some values cannot be accessed and unity is giving me a warning that says

```
Serialization depth limit 10 exceeded at 'Audio.data'. There may be an object composition cycle in one or more of your serialized classes.

Serialization hierarchy:
11: Audio.data
10: Attributes.Audio
9: Datum.attributes
8: Audio.data
7: Attributes.Audio
6: Datum.attributes
5: Audio.data
4: Attributes.Audio
3: Datum.attributes
2: Audio.data
1: Attributes.Audio
0: Datum.attributes
```

```html
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "attributes": {
        "LanguageName": "Bagari",
        "LanguageNameHindi": "बागड़ी",
        "LanguageNameGujarati": "બગારી",
        "SpokenBy": "1890815",
        "Description": "Bagadi is a prominent dialect of Rajasthan. It is mostly spoken in northern part of Rajasthan, southern part of Punjab and western part of Haryana. Although an independent dialect, it has great impact of Marwari and Deswali. It is not a language belonging to a particular caste or class but spoken by almost all the people of the area. In Rajasthan, the Bagadi dialect is spoken in the districts of Sri Ganganagar, Hanumangarh and Churu; in Haryana in Sirsa, Fatehbad, northern and eastern parts of Hisar districts and in Fazilka and Bathinda districts of Punjab. The users of this dialect are called ‘Bagadi’ or ‘Bagadiye’\n\nLet us see a bit of history of Bagadi language. This dialect has a long history. It takes its name from its native Bagar tract region of  the Northwestern India. It is the area where once flowed the river Saraswati and Hristati . The fertile area surrounding these two rivers is also known as ‘Aryavart’ and ‘Saraswat Pradesh’. \n\nBagadi is a folk dialect. It does not have any documented history or literature, but there are many folksongs and folktales in this dialect. The folk deity Gogaji of Rajasthan belongs to Bagad region. Therefore, he is also called “Bagad pir”. Pir is a title given to a revered and knowledgeable  person having many followers. The devotees sing the folk songs containing tales of the Bagad Pir. These songs are called ‘Jhedau’ in Bagadi. They are sung by the Somaiyas of the region.\n\nThis language is grammatically independent. It has its own vocabulary and a distinct articulation. It has its own characteristic nouns, pronouns, gender, verbs, adjectives, affixation etc. Its grammar is different from Hindi. However, the alphabets of this language do not differ from Rajasthani.",
        "DescriptionHindi": "राजस्थान की इक प्रमुख भाषा यानि बागडी भाषा। उत्तर राजस्थान, दक्षिण पंजाब और पश्चिम हरियाणा के लोग \nयह भाषा  बोलते हैं। यह भाषा किसी विशेष जाती या वर्ग के लोग ही बोलतें हैं ऐसा कत ही नहीं, इस प्रदेश में बसे हुए बहुसंख्य लोग यह भाषा बोलतें हैं। राजस्थान के श्री गंगानगर, हनुमानगढ और चुरु जिलों में यह भाषा बोली जाती है। हरियाणा में सिरसा जिला, फतेहबाद जिला और हिसर जिले के उत्तर और पूर्व क्षेत्रों में  यह भाषा बोली जाती है। पंजाब के भटिंडा और फझिल्का जिलों में  बागडी बोली जाती है।  यह भाषा बोलनेवाले ‘बागडी’ या ‘बागडिये’ कहेलातें हैं।\nअब इस भाषा का इतिहास देखेंगे। इसका इतिहास लंबा है। बागडी - इस भाषा का  नाम उत्तर-पश्चिम भारत के उसके मूल वतन बागर प्रदेश से आया है। इक समय था जब यहां दो नदियाँ बहती थीं: सरस्वती और ह्रष्टाती नदी। इन नदियों का परिसर  आर्यावर्त और सारस्वत प्रदेश से भी जाना जाता है। \n\nबागडी इक लोक-भाषा है। इस भाषा के इतिहास या साहित्य के कोई लिखित दस्तावेज उपलब्ध नहीं हैं। राजस्थान के लोगों के माने हुए देव गोगाजी का मूल वतन बागड प्रदेश। इसिलिए वे ‘बागड के पिर’ कहेलातें हैं। पिर माने  पूजनीय और ज्ञानी व्यक्ति जिनके बहुत सारें भक्त एवम् अनुयायी होतें हैं। बागड पिर की गाथा बागडी भक्तों के लोकगीतों में अक्सर सुनने में आती है। यह लोकगीत ‘झेडाउ’ नाम से जाने जातें हैं। इस प्रदेश सोमैया लोग झेडाउ गातें हैं।\nव्याकरण की द्रष्टिसे यह भाषा  स्वतंत्र है। इस का अपना शब्द-भंडार है। इस का अपना ही इक बोलने  का लहेजा है। इस भाषा के खास विशिष्ट ऐसे नाम, सर्वनाम, विशेषण, क्रियापद और उपसर्ग है। हालांकि उसकी वर्णमाला राजस्थानी से कत ही अलग नहीं है।",
        "DescriptionGujarati": "રાજસ્થાનની એક બહુ જ અગત્યની બોલી એટલે બાગડી બોલી. આ બોલી ઉત્તર રાજસ્થાન, દક્ષિણ પંજાબ અને પશ્ચિમ હરિયાણાના લોકો બોલે છે. આ બોલી કોઈ વિશેષ જાતી કે વર્ગમાં બોલાય છે તેવું નથી, આ પ્રદેશમાં વસતા મોટાભાગના લોકો આ બોલી બોલે છે. રાજસ્થાનના શ્રી ગંગાનગર, હનુમાનગઢ અને ચુરુ જિલ્લાઓમાં આ બોલી બોલાય છે. હરિયાણામાં સિરસા જિલ્લા, ફતેહબાદ જિલ્લા અને હિસર જિલ્લાના ઉત્તર તેમજ પૂર્વ ભાગોમાં આ બોલી બોલાય છે. પંજાબના ભટિંડા તથા ફઝિલ્કા જિલ્લાઓમાં બાગડી વપરાય છે. આ બોલી બોલનારા લોકોને ‘બાગડી’ અથવા ‘બાગડિયે’ લોકો તરીકે ઓળખવામાં આવે છે.\nઆ ભાષાનો થોડો ઇતિહાસ જોઈએ. તેનો ઇતિહાસ લાંબો છે. બાગડી નામ ઉત્તર-પશ્ચિમ ભારતમાં આવેલા તેના મૂળ વતન બાગર પ્રદેશ પરથી આવ્યંુ છે. એક સમયે અહીં સરસ્વતી અને હૃસ્ટાતી નદીઓ વહેતી હતી. નદીઓનો ફળદ્રુપ પરિસર આર્યાવર્ત અને સારસ્વત પ્રદેશ તરીકે પણ ઓળખાય છે. \nબાગડી એક લોકબોલી છે. તેના ઇતિહાસ કે સાહિત્યના કોઈ લેખિત દસ્તાવેજ નથી, પણ લોકગીતો અને લોકકથાઓ પ્રસિદ્ધ છે. રાજસ્થાનના લોકોના માનીતા દેવ ગોગાજી બાગડ પ્રદેશના વતની હતા. તેઓ ‘બાગડપીર’ તરીકે જાણીતા છે. પીર એટલે પૂજનીય અને જ્ઞાની તેવી વ્યક્તિ  જેને બહોળા પ્રમાણમાં અનુયાયીઓ હોય.  બાગડપીરની ગાથા બાગડી ભક્તો જે ગાતા હોય છે તે લોકગીતોમાં વણાયેલી છે. આ ગીતોને બાગડી ભાષામાં ઝૈડો કહેવાય છે. આ પ્રદેશના સોમૈયાઓ ઝૈડો ગાતા હોય છે. \nઆ ભાષા વ્યાકરણની દ્રષ્ટિએ સ્વતંત્ર છે. તેનો પોતાનો શબ્દ ભંડોળ છે. તેની એક આગવી એવી બોલવાની લઢણ છે. તેનાં પોતાનાં લાક્ષણિક નામ, સર્વનામ, લિંગ, પ્રત્યય, ક્રિયાપદ, વિશેષણો, ઉપસર્ગો અને વિસ્મયદર્શકો છે. તેનું વ્યાકરણ હિન્દી કરતાં જુદું છે. જો કે, તેની વર્ણમાલા રાજસ્થાની કરતાં જરાક પણ જુદી નથી.",
        "LanguageID": 1,
        "Location": "Rajasthan",
        "BgColor": "4C1D4F",
        "createdAt": "2022-12-18T12:18:39.730Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-12-20T06:01:04.199Z",
        "publishedAt": "2022-12-18T12:18:46.386Z",
        "FgColor": "FFFFFF",
        "Audio": {
          "data": {
            "id": 14,
            "attributes": {
              "name": "Bagari_002_2146828a5a.mp3",
              "alternativeText": null,
              "caption": null,
              "width": null,
              "height": null,
              "formats": null,
              "hash": "Bagari_002_2146828a5a_34d197f701",
              "ext": ".mp3",
              "mime": "audio/mpeg",
              "size": 1166.77,
              "url": "/uploads/Bagari_002_2146828a5a_34d197f701.mp3",
              "previewUrl": null,
              "provider": "local",
              "provider_metadata": null,
              "createdAt": "2022-12-19T11:52:19.807Z",
              "updatedAt": "2022-12-19T11:52:19.807Z"
            }
          }
        },
        "AudioHindi": {
          "data": {
            "id": 13,
            "attributes": {
              "name": "Bagari_036_fb7709041d.mp3",
              "alternativeText": null,
              "caption": null,
              "width": null,
              "height": null,
              "formats": null,
              "hash": "Bagari_036_fb7709041d_0e206e6947",
              "ext": ".mp3",
              "mime": "audio/mpeg",
              "size": 1072.52,
              "url": "/uploads/Bagari_036_fb7709041d_0e206e6947.mp3",
              "previewUrl": null,
              "provider": "local",
              "provider_metadata": null,
              "createdAt": "2022-12-19T11:52:15.153Z",
              "updatedAt": "2022-12-19T11:52:15.153Z"
            }
          }
        },
        "AudioGujarati": {
          "data": {
            "id": 12,
            "attributes": {
              "name": "Bagari_002_2146828a5a.mp3",
              "alternativeText": null,
              "caption": null,
              "width": null,
              "height": null,
              "formats": null,
              "hash": "Bagari_002_2146828a5a_fa74dbc558",
              "ext": ".mp3",
              "mime": "audio/mpeg",
              "size": 1166.77,
              "url": "/uploads/Bagari_002_2146828a5a_fa74dbc558.mp3",
              "previewUrl": null,
              "provider": "local",
              "provider_metadata": null,
              "createdAt": "2022-12-19T11:51:58.842Z",
              "updatedAt": "2022-12-19T11:51:58.842Z"
            }
          }
        },
        "Video1": {
          "data": {
            "id": 19,
            "attributes": {
              "name": "Bagri Language Speaking.mp4",
              "alternativeText": null,
              "caption": null,
              "width": null,
              "height": null,
              "formats": null,
              "hash": "Bagri_Language_Speaking_708ea33ca6",
              "ext": ".mp4",
              "mime": "video/mp4",
              "size": 29219.54,
              "url": "/uploads/Bagri_Language_Speaking_708ea33ca6.mp4",
              "previewUrl": null,
              "provider": "local",
              "provider_metadata": null,
              "createdAt": "2022-12-20T06:00:11.638Z",
              "updatedAt": "2022-12-20T06:00:11.638Z"
            }
          }
        },
        "Video2": {
          "data": null
        },
        "Video3": {
          "data": null
        },
        "MapImage": {
          "data": {
            "id": 15,
            "attributes": {
              "name": "Bagdi.svg.jpg",
              "alternativeText": null,
              "caption": null,
              "width": 2453,
              "height": 1552,
              "formats": {
                "thumbnail": {
                  "name": "thumbnail_Bagdi.svg.jpg",
                  "hash": "thumbnail_Bagdi_svg_2a65b39ef2",
                  "ext": ".jpg",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "path": null,
                  "width": 245,
                  "height": 155,
                  "size": 5.55,
                  "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_Bagdi_svg_2a65b39ef2.jpg"
                },
                "medium": {
                  "name": "medium_Bagdi.svg.jpg",
                  "hash": "medium_Bagdi_svg_2a65b39ef2",
                  "ext": ".jpg",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "path": null,
                  "width": 750,
                  "height": 475,
                  "size": 37.13,
                  "url": "/uploads/medium_Bagdi_svg_2a65b39ef2.jpg"
                },
                "small": {
                  "name": "small_Bagdi.svg.jpg",
                  "hash": "small_Bagdi_svg_2a65b39ef2",
                  "ext": ".jpg",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "path": null,
                  "width": 500,
                  "height": 316,
                  "size": 19.34,
                  "url": "/uploads/small_Bagdi_svg_2a65b39ef2.jpg"
                },
                "large": {
                  "name": "large_Bagdi.svg.jpg",
                  "hash": "large_Bagdi_svg_2a65b39ef2",
                  "ext": ".jpg",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "path": null,
                  "width": 1000,
                  "height": 633,
                  "size": 58.3,
                  "url": "/uploads/large_Bagdi_svg_2a65b39ef2.jpg"
                }
              },
              "hash": "Bagdi_svg_2a65b39ef2",
              "ext": ".jpg",
              "mime": "image/jpeg",
              "size": 124.08,
              "url": "/uploads/Bagdi_svg_2a65b39ef2.jpg",
              "previewUrl": null,
              "provider": "local",
              "provider_metadata": null,
              "createdAt": "2022-12-19T11:52:45.721Z",
              "updatedAt": "2022-12-19T11:52:45.721Z"
            }
          }
        },
        "Image1": {
          "data": {
            "id": 16,
            "attributes": {
              "name": "ss011.jpeg",
              "alternativeText": null,
              "caption": null,
              "width": 1160,
              "height": 652,
              "formats": {
                "thumbnail": {
                  "name": "thumbnail_ss011.jpeg",
                  "hash": "thumbnail_ss011_938b6fd8c4",
                  "ext": ".jpeg",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "path": null,
                  "width": 245,
                  "height": 138,
                  "size": 8.91,
                  "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_ss011_938b6fd8c4.jpeg"
                },
                "medium": {
                  "name": "medium_ss011.jpeg",
                  "hash": "medium_ss011_938b6fd8c4",
                  "ext": ".jpeg",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "path": null,
                  "width": 750,
                  "height": 422,
                  "size": 54.74,
                  "url": "/uploads/medium_ss011_938b6fd8c4.jpeg"
                },
                "small": {
                  "name": "small_ss011.jpeg",
                  "hash": "small_ss011_938b6fd8c4",
                  "ext": ".jpeg",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "path": null,
                  "width": 500,
                  "height": 281,
                  "size": 28.2,
                  "url": "/uploads/small_ss011_938b6fd8c4.jpeg"
                },
                "large": {
                  "name": "large_ss011.jpeg",
                  "hash": "large_ss011_938b6fd8c4",
                  "ext": ".jpeg",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "path": null,
                  "width": 1000,
                  "height": 562,
                  "size": 87.05,
                  "url": "/uploads/large_ss011_938b6fd8c4.jpeg"
                }
              },
              "hash": "ss011_938b6fd8c4",
              "ext": ".jpeg",
              "mime": "image/jpeg",
              "size": 105.5,
              "url": "/uploads/ss011_938b6fd8c4.jpeg",
              "previewUrl": null,
              "provider": "local",
              "provider_metadata": null,
              "createdAt": "2022-12-20T05:59:47.562Z",
              "updatedAt": "2022-12-20T05:59:47.562Z"
            }
          }
        },
        "Image2": {
          "data": {
            "id": 17,
            "attributes": {
              "name": "ss004.jpeg",
              "alternativeText": null,
              "caption": null,
              "width": 1160,
              "height": 652,
              "formats": {
                "thumbnail": {
                  "name": "thumbnail_ss004.jpeg",
                  "hash": "thumbnail_ss004_9d1881b5d3",
                  "ext": ".jpeg",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "path": null,
                  "width": 245,
                  "height": 138,
                  "size": 7.97,
                  "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_ss004_9d1881b5d3.jpeg"
                },
                "medium": {
                  "name": "medium_ss004.jpeg",
                  "hash": "medium_ss004_9d1881b5d3",
                  "ext": ".jpeg",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "path": null,
                  "width": 750,
                  "height": 422,
                  "size": 63.19,
                  "url": "/uploads/medium_ss004_9d1881b5d3.jpeg"
                },
                "small": {
                  "name": "small_ss004.jpeg",
                  "hash": "small_ss004_9d1881b5d3",
                  "ext": ".jpeg",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "path": null,
                  "width": 500,
                  "height": 281,
                  "size": 30.58,
                  "url": "/uploads/small_ss004_9d1881b5d3.jpeg"
                },
                "large": {
                  "name": "large_ss004.jpeg",
                  "hash": "large_ss004_9d1881b5d3",
                  "ext": ".jpeg",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "path": null,
                  "width": 1000,
                  "height": 562,
                  "size": 100.99,
                  "url": "/uploads/large_ss004_9d1881b5d3.jpeg"
                }
              },
              "hash": "ss004_9d1881b5d3",
              "ext": ".jpeg",
              "mime": "image/jpeg",
              "size": 122.41,
              "url": "/uploads/ss004_9d1881b5d3.jpeg",
              "previewUrl": null,
              "provider": "local",
              "provider_metadata": null,
              "createdAt": "2022-12-20T05:59:53.317Z",
              "updatedAt": "2022-12-20T05:59:53.317Z"
            }
          }
        },
        "Image3": {
          "data": {
            "id": 18,
            "attributes": {
              "name": "ss012.jpeg",
              "alternativeText": null,
              "caption": null,
              "width": 1160,
              "height": 652,
              "formats": {
                "thumbnail": {
                  "name": "thumbnail_ss012.jpeg",
                  "hash": "thumbnail_ss012_f0e17e9f58",
                  "ext": ".jpeg",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "path": null,
                  "width": 245,
                  "height": 138,
                  "size": 11.53,
                  "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_ss012_f0e17e9f58.jpeg"
                },
                "small": {
                  "name": "small_ss012.jpeg",
                  "hash": "small_ss012_f0e17e9f58",
                  "ext": ".jpeg",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "path": null,
                  "width": 500,
                  "height": 281,
                  "size": 40.59,
                  "url": "/uploads/small_ss012_f0e17e9f58.jpeg"
                },
                "medium": {
                  "name": "medium_ss012.jpeg",
                  "hash": "medium_ss012_f0e17e9f58",
                  "ext": ".jpeg",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "path": null,
                  "width": 750,
                  "height": 422,
                  "size": 77.75,
                  "url": "/uploads/medium_ss012_f0e17e9f58.jpeg"
                },
                "large": {
                  "name": "large_ss012.jpeg",
                  "hash": "large_ss012_f0e17e9f58",
                  "ext": ".jpeg",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "path": null,
                  "width": 1000,
                  "height": 562,
                  "size": 119.83,
                  "url": "/uploads/large_ss012_f0e17e9f58.jpeg"
                }
              },
              "hash": "ss012_f0e17e9f58",
              "ext": ".jpeg",
              "mime": "image/jpeg",
              "size": 143.52,
              "url": "/uploads/ss012_f0e17e9f58.jpeg",
              "previewUrl": null,
              "provider": "local",
              "provider_metadata": null,
              "createdAt": "2022-12-20T05:59:58.608Z",
              "updatedAt": "2022-12-20T05:59:58.608Z"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "page": 1,
      "pageSize": 25,
      "pageCount": 1,
      "total": 1
    }
  }
}
```

I have no idea what i'm doing and need immediate help in resolving this. How do I generate classes for this JSON? What should I ideally use to parse this? How to parse this?

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 1):

With NewtonSoft.JSON it is possible to [deserialize to an anonymous type](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) or to a [dictionary](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm). Assuming you know exactly the keys you want to access, this is the quick and dirty way

For example, accessing the LanguageNameHindi field from the anon obj would be
`string langNameHindiAnon = jsonAnon.data[0].attributes.LanguageNameHindi;`

Given the complexity of the JSON, the dictionary approach looks like it would be hell

But to be honest, if you want the most maintainability out of it (i.e. the easiest to debug), take the time to architect the classes that this JSON is meant to deserialize to, and do it the [long way](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm). For something this big and structured, personally I would invest the time upfront to ensure it deserializes to a proper model

Comment: How would I access the content further inside like the url from Audio or caption from Image1?

Comment: Audio from anon: `jsonAnon.data[n].attributes.Audio.data.attributes.url` where *n* is the specific element of the array you want to access. As you can see, you have to follow the entire downward cascade of the JSON objects and arrays involved in the JSON to reach what you want

Comment: Yes, this will probably be a nightmare to debug, hence why I recommend in my original answer, situations this complex it is much better in the long run to craft the classes to deserialize to. In the course of figuring out the JSON structure you will figure out the class hierarchies anyway. `{}` denotes a JSON object which becomes a POCO, while `[]` denotes a JSON array which becomes `List<T>` in C# where *T* are class objects you define

Comment: You may want to try out [this tool](https://json2csharp.com/), but I can make **no** guarantees as to how accurate or correct the outputs are. I've played around with the tool only briefly and it seemed good though. Ideally try to feed it JSON with as few nulls as possible as it won't know how to type it at that point